# Computing Cronbach’s Alpha for Test with Random Items

Tags: consistency

I need to find out Cronbach's Alpha for a test that pulls 10 questions randomly from a pool of 40 questions for every subject that takes the test. As a result, almost every test has a different set of questions.

I thought that I could compute CA for the 40 questions and leave unanswered items as missing values, but I'm afraid this might affect the variance of the items.

The sample is not big enough to find a subset of subjects that has answered exactly the same questions (n=50).

Comment: Unless those 40 questions are all measuring the same thing Cronbach's alpha is uninterpretable: it is useful only for *unidimensional* data (i.e. a set of variables all sharing a single underlying dimension of variance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in a reasonable way, although there may be some program that would compute it.

The full test has 40 questions, so that is 40*39/2 = 780 correlations to measure.

You have 50 copies of 10 random questions, which is 10*9/2 = 45 correlations so you have 450 points of data to estimate 780. Many of your correlations will be either missing or inestimable because only one person will answer both questions.